# Add conditional where clause for two different columns in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to write a query where I need to append where clause based on the input value available from two different places on client. For ex. I get only id from one page and from other page I get date range to filter records .

In both conditions query result is same , so I was thinking of how should I write a where clause based on input (Either Id or date range)

E.g. - Employee table:

If from one screen I am having id and from other date range , so I want to build a dynamic query in oracle sql to fetch result set -

```
select * (required columns) from employee 
where 
-- other filter criteria     
and if {employee_id is received} then id = ${employee_id} 
else if {date range is received} then joining_date between {date range}
```

NOTE : Also there are multiple tables in JOIN , which I have not included here. 
Any help will be appreciated . :)

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this helps; this example is based on Scott's sample `EMP` table (as I don't have your tables), so - in order to test the query, I used what I have.

```
select deptno, empno, ename, job, hiredate
from emp
where (    empno = :par_empno
       or :par_empno is null
      )
  and (    hiredate between :par_date_from and :par_date_to
       or (:par_date_from is null and :par_date_to is null)
      );
```